# JodaTime: How to get a String representation in the format "HH:mm Z" from a LocalTime

Tags: java, kotlin, timezone, jodatime

Assume we have a Joda `LocalTime` and want to display its hour and minute and timezone, how to do it?

Actually this doesn't work:

```
 val chronology= ISOChronology.getInstance(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/St_Vincent")))
 val localTime = LocalTime(12, 45, 0, 0, chronology)
 val string = localTime.toString("HH:mm Z") // returns "12:45 ", expected "12:45 -4"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local times does not have an attached timezone by definition. But a `Chronology` is not a timezone, it's a way people measure time (like Chinese years, or Buddhist). You could omit it in your code and the result would be the same as `ISOChronology` (the way we measure time in "Western Culture") is the default.

You need to turn it into a zoned date time:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val localTime = LocalTime(12, 45, 0, 0)
    val string = localTime
            .toDateTimeToday(
                    DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/St_Vincent"))
            )
            .toString("HH:mm Z")

    println(string)
}
```

The result is: `12:45 -0400`